# Projection of frustum on cube

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, projection

We have a camera $C$ and two parallel planes $A$ amd $B$, $near$=$dist(C, A)$, $far=dist(C,B)$. The matrix which maps points in frustum (defined as the space surrounded by these two planes and a couple of lines) on a cube with side 1 is given by \begin{bmatrix}\frac fa&0&0&0\\0&f&0&0\\0&0&x&y\\0&0&-1&0\end{bmatrix} where $a$ is the scale we need to project to a screen ( because it may be bigger or smaller , $x=((near+far)/(near-far))$, $y=(2.near.far)/(near-far)$.
I don't understand how is this matrix derived, why we scale only the first $f$, why do we have $-1$ on the 4th row 3rd column. Here is a picture ( with different annotations ): [image] Thank you in advance.

Comment: What is the source of this (that is, where did you read about it)? Evidently they want to do something with this matrix, but I cannot guess what. You might try giving some more context if possible.

Comment: Hey! We studied this at university, but basically I am writing what was there. The only difference is the picture I have found on internet.

Comment: Where is "there"? Did you get a message in a bottle and this was all that was written on it? There's always context to a problem like this. I don't think you've provided enough for anyone to answer.

Comment: Sir, this is the problem: 3D space is infinite, so we need to limit what is shown on a screen. So we define a matrix M which maps a 3D subspace to a screen. I have given the matrix. f defines the screen mapping ( I would say that is the distance from the camera to the screen). I have defined everything else (except for a, which is the thing I don't understand). The third row of the matrix is the Z mapping.

Comment: Also 'there' is a couple of slides.

Answer (score 1):

The first f is scaled by the aspect ratio, otherwise you are stuck with a square viewport instead of a rectangle one.

x and y values are scaled by f to take into account the angle of view.

The "-1" is to store the z value as depth in w coordinate. The minus is for flipping the axes.

The x and y fields with `near` and `far` are for mapping the z value between near and far to -1 to 1.

All three x, y and z coordinates need a division by original z, which is stored in w thanks to that "1" (or "-1").